# Want to implement multiple database in django project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to use multiple sqlite3 database for my app. I want to write some of the data(which is user log) to one database  and rest of the stuff to another db. After that I want to read from both the database. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['manager.router.DatabaseAppsRouter']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = { 'db_b':'db_b'}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'backend_of_your_choice', 
            'NAME': 'default',                    
            'USER': 'xxx',                      
            'PASSWORD': 'xxx',                  
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                     
            'PORT': '',                      
    },

    'db_b': {
            'ENGINE': 'backend_of_your_choice', 
            'NAME': 'db_b',                    
            'USER': 'xxx',                      
            'PASSWORD': 'xxx',                  
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      
            'PORT': '',               
},}
```

Then in your model `MetaClass` define the following for all the models which you want to use db_b:

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'db_b'
```

Comment: I am facing error in  --File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named manager.router